# Creating persistent graphics from other functions in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, graphics, drawing

My program will display the status of a piece of industrial equipment by plotting coloured points as the program runs to produce a plan of the machine's current state.  However, I'm struggling to figure out these graphics methods.  I had a straightforward solution with creategraphics, but I gather that's disliked and it would clear the graphics on redraw.

I understand I can add graphics in the paint event.  However, what if I want a function I can call to add a specific element to the plot?
E.g.

```
Dim Diagram as New '...Something?

Public Sub Drawx(ByVal x as single, ByVal y as single)
    'Adds an x mark to the diagram with the specified coordinates
End Sub

Private Sub Status_Paint(sender As Object, e As Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    'Redraws all x marks thus far added to the diagram
End Sub
```

But with e.graphics being read only, I'm not sure how to add graphics like this outside the paint event.  Can I set some kind of reference to e.graphics in the paint event, then draw on that in the public function?

Comment: Dont draw outside the Paint event.  Set variables which your Paint code uses to draw whatever.  You should be using `e.Graphics` not trying to replace it...not sure that the Readonly part means.

Comment: I was hoping I could create a new graphics object to draw to and set e.Graphics equal to it.  That doesn't seem to be how it works.

Comment: thats not how you want it to work if you want persistence.  everytime something passes over the form then moves away your diagram will have to be repainted, so you want that in the Paint event.

Comment: Your Paint event handler can of course call a method like Drawx().  You however need to add an extra argument of type Graphics so it can draw with the correct Graphics object.